# Remove a property in SQL Server JSON data with serialized JSON as a property inside

Tags: json, sql-server

I have some JSON data in SQL Server so that the `JsonEntity` within this JSON data is actually serialized JSON data passed from code. I need to update this data using SQL Server, so that I need to remove one of the property within the serialized JSON.

The following is a sample data item.

```
{
    "EventID": 901416,
    "SiteID": 11394,
    "JsonEntity": "{\"ContactDTO\":{\"Contact\":{\"ContactByEmail\":true,\"ContactBySMS\":false,\"ContactID\":\"400002\",\"CustomerID\":\"300001\"},\"RecipientType\":\"Responder\"},\"ContactName\":\"Tester\", \"Method\":\"Email\"}",
    "TemplateID": 20001
}
```

I need to remove all occurrences of `ContactDTO` from within the Json so that the data should look like

```
{
    "EventID": 901416,
    "SiteID": 11394,
    "JsonEntity":"{\"ContactName\":\"Tester\",\"Method\":\"Email\"}",
    "TemplateID": 20001
}
```

I have been fiddling around with `JSON_MODIFY` and `JSON_VALUE` without much success

Comment: ...why are you storing JSON blobs inside a table instead of using _normalized data_ in your RDBMS? (and I see you also have JSON-inside-a-string-inside-JSON... why are you doing this?)

Comment: `select json_modify(@json, '$.JsonEntity', string_escape(json_modify(json_value(@json, '$.JsonEntity'), '$.ContactDTO', null), 'json'))`

Comment: We have a generic application to create tabular UI without having to create code changes. Hence the json data.

Comment: @lptr Thanks for that. This was almost exactly what I was after. (Had to make a minor adjustment to get rid of the extra slashes)